# saving this repeated string as a new variable

Tags: java

```
Intlength3 = Intlength/Intlength2;
System.out.println(Intlength3); 

for (int l=0; l<Intlength3; l++){ 
    System.out.print(strKeyword);
```

I have made the `strKeyword` be repeated a number of times. however I want to save this as a new variable called `newKeyword`. if this `Intlength` was 6 and the `Intlength2` was 3, the calculation 6/3 would take place and give me 2. Therefore on the last line you can see, the keyword would thus be repeated twice. However I want to save this repeated keyword as a new variable so that I can use the `newKeyword` later on. How can I add this into this specific part of programming.

Comment: Note, in Java the convention is to start variables with lowercase and do not prefix the type, that's old school for when IDEs were less informative.

Comment: i will correct it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Intlength3 = Intlength/Intlength2;
System.out.println(Intlength3); 

String newKeyword = "";

for (int l=0; l<Intlength3; l++){ 
    System.out.print(strKeyword);
    newKeyword += strKeyword;
}
```

Comment: it did not work, i also tried editing it however this still did now work.

Comment: nothing is wrony. from the last line you can see that the keyword gets repeated according to what the user enters. if the user enters cat it would come out as catcatcat but how do i save this as a seperate varibale to use later on